# Pass typescript type Problem in type-graphql

Tags: typescript, mongoose, graphql, typegraphql, typegoose

I am new with GraphQL and I don't know how to pass a TypeScript `type` to `ReturnTypeFunction` of `@Field` decorator.

my code is as below :

```js
export type WorokingHours = [number, number];

// [ [ 8, 13 ], [ 16, 22 ] ]
@Field(() => [WorokingHours], {
   nullable: true,
   description: storeWorkingHours
})
@prop()
workingHours?: WorokingHours[];
```

and I will get this error message:

```
'WorokingHours' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)
```

how can fix this error?

do you have any idea to implement the duration that my stores are actives in my DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GraphQL spec doesn't support tuples, so you need to use list `[Number]` or explicit object type `{ one: number, two: number }` instead.

Answer (score 0):

its simple, you have defined an `type`, which only exists at compilation time of typescript, not on runtime

for typegoose you need to manually set an array type anyways, for you case (on 7.2.0) it would be prop options `{ type: Number, dim: 2 }`

and for GraphQL i guess it would be `() => [[Number]]`